# What is the cause of this exception .?

Tags: behat, goutte

I am trying to run Behat\mink using this code "bin\behat --format html --out report.html --profile firefox" . But i am getting this error .

```
[RuntimeException]
MinkExtension 1.3 only supports Goutte 1.x for MinkGoutteDriver, not Goutte 2.x.
```

composer.json looks like this

```
{
"require": {
    "behat/behat": "2.5.*@stable",
    "behat/mink": "1.6.*@stable",
    "behat/mink-extension": "*",
    "behat/mink":"~1.5@dev",
    "behat/mink":"~1.6@dev",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*"        
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin/"
}
}
```

behat.yml

```
firefox:
context:
   parameters:
       Browser_Name: firefox
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:            
        base_url: https://google.com
        javascript_session: selenium2
        browser_name: firefox            
        selenium2:
            wd_host: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
```

It would be so helpful if you could tell me where i have gone wrong .

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your first problem lies within your composer.json file.  It would appear as though you are attempting to load both developmental and stable versions of the same library.

Unless you are attempting to test / load some dev code you can simplify your require section to:

```
"require": {
"behat/mink-selenium2-driver"   : "~1.2",
"behat/mink-goutte-driver"      : "~1.1",
"behat/mink-extension"          : "~2.0"
}
```

Your behat/behat, and behat/mink libraries will automatically be pulled in by composer to fulfil the requirements for those libraries.

Information on the tilde operator, within your composer.json file can be found [within composers documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#next-significant-release-tilde-and-caret-operators-)

Again, unless you are using dev based releases you might want to look at omitting:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```